# Canot create ArrayListAdapter in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created a custom adapter to display a list of Alarm objects in my fragments view. I've looked at multiple post and tutorials and I think I finally got it right. I made my adapters constructor take an ArrayList of Alarms. However when I try to create an adapter inside of my fragment, I get the message

> AdapterAlarm(Context, java.util.ArrayList   com.runners.spo.Alarm>) in
>   Adapter Alarm cannot be applied to (FragmentActivity,
>   java.util.List      com.runners.spo.Alarm>)

My adapter looks like:

```
public class AdapterAlarm extends ArrayAdapter<Alarm> {
    public AdapterAlarm(Context context, ArrayList<Alarm> alarms) {
        super(context, R.layout.alarm_item, alarms);
    }

     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layout = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customview = layout.inflate(R.layout.alarm_item, parent, false);

        String name = getItem(position).name;
        ...

        TextView updatename = (TextView)customview.findViewById(R.id.name);
        ...

        updatename.setText(name);
        ...

        return customview;
    }
```

I am trying it to use the adapter inside a the fragment as such.

```
private List<Alarm> alarms = new ArrayList<Alarm>();
private AdapterAlarm alarmAdapter;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);
        //this or getActivity()
        //problem is here
        alarmAdapter = new AdapterAlarm(this, alarms);
        ...
```

I'm quite lost on how to handle this problem. I'm not sure what is wrong with the list.

Comment: Alarm is your pojo class then pl change name

Comment: @AndroidTeam, what do you mean by "pl change name"? I get that Alarm is my pojo and that I'm creating a list of Alarm Objects, but what is the thing I should be changing the name of?

Comment: if you get pojo class extact than only change this.

Comment: change this things 
        alarmAdapter = new AdapterAlarm(getActivity(), alarms);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AdapterAlarm class expects an `ArrayList<Alarm>`, but you give it just a `List<Alarm>`.
That's what the error message says.